# Drupal - how to add add same page to two menus?

Tags: drupal, menu, hook

How can I add same callback to 2 different menus?

```
function my_callback_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['my_callback'] = array(
    'title'            => t('My title'),    
    'menu_name'        => 'menu-my-menu',   
        'page callback'    => 'my_callback',         
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),            
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many menu items with `hook_menu` as you want. All of them can be assigned to the same callback function if you make the `page callback` value the same name.

Comment: You might want to find a way to wipe the redundant page from the search index. You might check the search_config module.

Comment: @Grayside I'm not saying you should do this, or even that it's a good idea, only that it's possible. Also the same callback function can provide different output if you use arguments, so it might not even be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are now a couple of solutions to this:

The module [multiple_node_menu](http://drupal.org/project/multiple_node_menu) answers the question without the hook. On a node you are able to put a menu item in two places and set the primary parent (router).

There is also [Node Symlinks](http://drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks) which works differently allowing the same content to be displayed in two different places in the website without an SEO penalty. (not what I was looking for)